# Trigger combobox change event

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-11, browser-automation

I am working with DATAGRID in web application now, having problem where i can select the object by code , change the value of combobox by code, yet it did no trigger the 'updates' in the application after the code executed.

Comment: Please check your code, I suppose you are using some Combobox plugin, and you will use it's select event to enter values into the text box. Then, trigger the change event. To trigger the change event from VBA, we could try to use the Application.SendKeys method to enter values into the text box, then, after losing focus, it will trigger the change event.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. it does not work . once it lost focus and click on other field using code, it will fall back original value (i.e no changes), from the surface of code itself , i cant see any html events. any way i can detect was it a plugin or not?

Comment: You could use F12 developer tools to check the html element and the related Javascript script (from the above code, it seems that this plugin might be using JQuery class selector, you could find the related script according it). can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we could test the code on our side, it might be easier for us to help you solve the problem.

Comment: thanks .the code is company property and i cant share too much to avoid unnecessary problem . anyway , thanks for always looking up for my problem =)